# Read part of binary file in javascript without loading whole file in memory

Tags: javascript, filereader

I need to read a very large local binary file in javascript (in a browser, not node). The file contains a header with the offsets and sizes chunks of data that I'll use. Since it's a large file, I don't want to load it all in memory. I want to read the header, and then only the chunks of data that I'll use (not all of them).

In C/C++ I can position myself in certain offset of a file without actually reading the whole file, but I cannot find a way to do this from a browser (not node). The FileReader object in javascript reads the whole argument before returning an array buffer. I cannot find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the answer by Pablo CG was correct, I decided to expand it with an example. Basically it took me a little while to understand how to implement it, so probably other people could be in the same situation in the future.

Basically, you just read the file by slices (as Pablo suggested), and *then* pass it to the fileReader (this is the part that took me some time to figure out):

```
window.onload = function() {

    if (window.File && window.FileReader) {
      // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    } else {
      alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    function handleFileSelect(evt)
    {
        var file = evt.target.files[0];

        if (file != undefined);
        {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let blob = file.slice(0, 2);

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var buffer = e.target.result;
                let dv = new DataView(buffer);
                let blockId = dv.getUint16(0,true);

                if (blockId.toString(16)!="3a55"){
                    throw "Wrong format. Not a SEG-2 file."; }
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);
}
```

In the example I only read the first two bytes of a binary file to determine if its indeed the type of file I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the file by slices, using File API:

`var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endingByte);`

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice